# What is the difference between func with parentheses and one without it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
 onHangeChangeQuanity = (opr) => {
    let { number } = this.state;
    if (opr === '+') {
      this.setState({ number: number+1 }, this.onSubmit);
    } else if (opr === '-' && number !== 0) {
      this.setState({ number: number-1 }, this.onSubmit());
    }
 }

onSubmit = () => {
   let { attributeName, typeOfField } = this.props.attribute;
   let { number } = this.state;
   let attr = { attributeName, typeOfField, selectedValues: [ number ] };
   this.props.onHandle(attr);
}
```

In the above example in my if condition `(opr === '+')` I call my onSubmit func without parentheses and it works find and show the current state of my `number` but in the else condition `(opr === '-' && number!==0)` I use `onSubmit()` with parentheses in my setState callback and it doesn't update the state like it should.

Can someone please explain the difference between a javascript function that is being called with and without parentheses.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [`setState` is not guaranteed to be synchronous](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate), it accepts a callback function as the second argument, which it will call after it has updated the component's state.

> There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to `setState` and calls may be batched for performance gains.

Passing the function as a reference **(without parentheses)** ensures that your `onSubmit` method will only be called after the component's state has updated and you can rely on `this.state` to contain the new value.

Calling the function yourself **(with parentheses)** means that your `onSubmit` method will always execute before this `this.state` has the correct value, because it will run before `setState` does. If this is intentional behaviour it may make more sense to write it explicitly.

```
this.onSubmit()
this.setState({ number: number-1 });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Without** parentheses you only access to it's reference. You can use it to pass the reference for example into another function or use it's properties, because every function is also an object. Look at an example

```js
function first(){
   console.log('first');
}

function second(func) { // this get an parameter which is a function
   func(); // And here I call it 
}

second(first); // Here I pass the function's reference
               // And actually call the second with parentheses
```

**With** parentheses you execute the body of that function

Answer (score 1):

With the parentheses, you are writing a function call. Without them, you are simply "referring" to the function.

A function call just executes the contents of the function and may or may not return a value. A function reference can be used juts like any other variable. You can pass it to other functions, assign it to another variable etc.

Why are function references useful?

Some functions, like `window.setTimeout`, take function references as parameters.

```
window.setTimeout(someFunc, 1000);
```

Here `someFunc` will be executed after 1 second. You don't add the parentheses because what you're saying is "I want *this* function to be called after some delay". Adding parentheses here would have called the function immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Calling a function without parenthesis is referring to the function not what it returns, it is just like assigning and calling it with parenthesis is calling the value of that method, the body of the function executes and may return the required.

Answer (score 0):

When a function name is followed by parenthesis, it is like we say I want to call the function. While when you pass in one or another place a function name, you just pass a copy of the reference to the function.

```js
function sayHello(){
    console.log('Hello');
}

// Here we call sayHello();
sayHello();

function executeAnotherFunction(func){
    // We request the execution of the function passed.
    func();
}

// Here we pass a reference of sayHello to executeAnotherFunction
executeAnotherFunction(sayHello);
```